# simulate RoundRobin (Writing File)

Tags: java, performance, io

Scenario:

1. variable number of records
2. Fix number of files where I need to write these records

Now I need to simulate RoundRobin in writing.
At the moment I have this snippet code:

```
currentFile = listFiles.get((int) countRecord % sizeListFiles);
currentFile.write(record);
countRecord++;
```

where listFiles is my ArrayList of fixed files where to write, and sizeListFiles of course is size of this ArrayList.

Problem is:
I think code is slowing down cause I/O.
I'd like to improve this, I mean, at the end, I just need to have a balance row count between all my files (so RoundRobin is not really necessary).

Is there any solution?

I need to clarify that I can't know a priori number of records (it's a ResultSet), so I can't even go with a simple integer division (totRecord/sizeFileList)

Comment: You said "Problem is: I think code is slowing down cause I/O". Why? Did you test this in any way?

Comment: If you have a spinning disk, the more files you write to the more the disk head has to move and the slower your program will be. This is even a problem with SSD when you have small writes.  I suggest writing to less files if you want to speed it up.

Comment: I just suppose it, because I have a roundrobin decision on which file I have to write, so (I suppose) it could slow down all process because every record I switch to another BufferedWriter

Comment: @RocAràjol Yeah, I suppose a slowing down because Peter's reply

Comment: Start by writing one to each file, increasing to two per file and then three etc up to some maximum.

Comment: @PeterLawrey what about last round? I could have 4 files with xyz (and xyz could be possibly really big) records more than last one (file)

Comment: @AntonioCalì if writing the entries to each file is a bottleneck, you must have a lot of them and the time to process each one must be pretty small. If the time to process each record is large, then the time it takes to write these files isn't important.

Comment: @PeterLawrey records are in memory (Pretty much a JavaBin)

Comment: @AntonioCalì but you are also writing them to files I assume.